# Cursor is not moving

Tags: c

I am making a notepad through a double linked list, I have made a cursor function that will move with the linked list. But when I insert characters in the linked list the cursor stays at the start, even though I am incrementing as follows:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
   COORD coord;
   coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main() {
struct DLLADT notepad;
init(&notepad);
char c; 

while (1) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    gotoxy(x, y);
    c = getch();

    if (c == 13) {
        insertDoubly(&notepad, '\n'); // User pressed Enter
        y++;
    } else {
        insertDoubly(&notepad, c);
        system("cls");
        printDoubly(&notepad);
        x++;
    }
}

return 0;
getch();
```

I am using codeblocks

Comment: A while loop is a god awful way to update the cursors position, aside from that it probably stays in the same place since you only ever pass it 0,0 as it's coords

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
```

above `while(1)`. You are resetting `x` and `y` to zero before you call `gotoxy` each time.

Comment: No problem, it happens.